# Securing embedded chat app against unauthorized use on third-party websites

Tags: javascript, security, http-headers

I have developed a chat application for companies to embed on their websites, e.g. on e-commerce platforms. This chat allows visitors (who are not logged in) to ask questions about products or services.

Now I want to secure this chat application so that only valid websites can embed the chat javascript snippet and send requests. However, since this chat is used by public visitors, I don't have a JWT that I can send along with the HTTP request.

Currently, I use API keys sent with each HTTP request from the chat app to a) identify the company using the chat and b) measure and limit requests per API key (usage, throttling, etc.).

The API key is public as it is visible in the HTTP headers and as a query parameter in the embedded Javascript tag. This means that theoretically someone could take the snippet and embed it on their website and thus spam the system with *unauthorized* requests.

Are there ways to make this even more secure? I assume this is a general problem for other snippets that are embedded on a public website, e.g. Google Analytics, Ads, etc.